# Reduce MySQL queries by saving result to textfile

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have an app that is posting data from android to some MySQL tables through PHP with a 10 second interval. The same PHP file does a lot of queries on some other tables in the same database and the result is downloaded and processed in the app (with DownloadWebPageTask).

I usually have between 20 and 30 clients connected this way. Most of the data each client query for is the same as for all the other clients. If 30 clients run the same query every 10th second, 180 queries will be run. In fact every client run several queries, some of them are run in a loop (looping through results of another query).

My question is: if I somehow produce a textfile containing the same data, and updating this textfile every x seconds, and let all the clients read this file instead of running the queries themself - is it a better approach? will it reduce serverload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is caching. You can either cache the data coming from your DB or cache the page itself. Below you can find few links on how do the same in PHP:

http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/php-caching.php
http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/output-caching-for-beginners/

And yes. This will reduce DB server load drastically.

Comment: I've read the articles in your links, and it seems really easy to implement. All of the data can be read from the cachefile, if it exists, otherwise it will get created and then read. It seems like a brilliant solution. Will it work well with the short cachetime (≈ 10 sec)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should consider using memcache.

It will let you store your data in memory which is even faster than files on disk or mysql queries.

What it will also do is reduce load on your database so you will be able to serve more users with the same server/database setup.

Memcache is very easy to use and there are lots of tutorials on the internet.

Here is one to get you started:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/faster-php-mysql-websites-in-minutes/

Comment: I would recommend memcache too but for lasse's requirement it is a overkill.